# What's wrong with "func :: String -> [Int]; func = read "[3,5,7]""

Tags: function, haskell, types, compiler-errors, type-signature

In a very simple module `test` where I have the following function

```
func :: String -> [Int]
func = read "[3,5,7]"
```

Since I have explicit type annotations, I expect to get `[3,5,7]` when I load the module `test` and call `func` in ghci. However, I got

```
    • No instance for (Read (String -> [Int]))
        arising from a use of ‘read’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: read "[3,5,7]"
      In an equation for ‘func’: func = read "[3,5,7]"
   |
11 | func = read "[3,5,7]"
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But when I do `read "[3,5,7]" :: [Int]`, `[3,5,7]` is returned as expected. Why an error was raised when I loaded the module instead?

Comment: `cd str = [ (fromEnum d) - 48 | d <- str, elem d '0'..'9']]` will take any string of single digits in any form, `cd "13579"` or `cd "[2,3,5,7]"` or `cd " 2 3 5"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function type is `String -> [Int]` but you didn't specify its argument so the compiler "thinks" that you want to return a function `String -> [Int]` instead of `[Int]`.

You probably want:

```
func :: String -> [Int]
func s = read s
```

and then use it as:

```
func "[3,5,7]"
```

or just:

```
func :: String -> [Int]
func _ = read "[3,5,7]"
```

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to read your string as a function of type `String -> [Int]`, rather than a list `[Int]`. However, `read` can not convert strings into  functions.

Try this instead:

```
myList :: [Int]
myList = read "[3,5,7]"
```